# Automatically share view to emails that have completed the Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have a file (Google Slide) and I want to automatically share to emails that have completed the Google form. Can I do that?

```
/**
 * Installs a trigger on the Spreadsheet for when a Form response is submitted.
 */

function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}


function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  var email = responses['Email Address'][0].trim();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1E6wiWnf7wIgM6DQk-qRQcndFOGgQSs4QFdvM6PGrKwE');
  file.addViewer(email);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code snippet, but there doesn't seem to be a question here.  Can you please write out the question you would like answered?

Comment: Thanks for reply me, I want to share a file to emails that have completed the Google form automatically, can I do that?

Comment: Hi everyone,
I'm newbie and I don't know about the script. Hope you guys help me. I have a file (Google Slide) and I want to automatically share to emails that have completed the Google form. Can I do that? Thank so much!

Comment: Isn't that what you're script is attempting to do? What's wrong with your script? See [mcve]

Comment: Hi TheMaster, I mean the script doesn't share view permirsion to those emails,

Comment: let me ask with my needs how to use the script

Comment: Have you set up the form submit trigger? Have you looked at the error messages in view> executions?

Comment: Hi, I think function installTrigger() { ... is form submit triggger. Forgive me because I don't now about js :(

Comment: I imitated this code
https://medium.com/google-cloud/send-content-automatically-via-a-google-sheet-and-an-apps-script-c65d82284f5f

Comment: Consider taking the "Codelabs" first. Then read the official documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for "Codelabs". Without you having a  basic understanding of how apps script operates, It's hard to help  you.

Comment: First, check if you have installed the trigger. To do this, go to `Edit > Current project's triggers`. Can you find your onFormSubmit trigger in the displayed page? If that's not the case, execute `installTrigger`. And if you can find the trigger, submit the form and look for the corresponding execution in `View > Executions`. Do you see any error message there?